# iTunes Artwork not working in iTunes 11.1.5

Tags: objective-c, macos, itunes, artwork

i have an app that gets the album artwork using SBApplication. I had this code:

```
NSImage* albumArtwork;
iTunesArtwork *artwork = (iTunesArtwork *)[[[[iTunes currentTrack] artworks] get] lastObject];
albumArtwork = artwork.data;
```

Now, with the latest iTunes 11.1.5 the artwork variable is always nil. I tried different approaches to read the album artwork, but nothing works.

Doses anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Do you have an `iTunes.h` file generated for your project? Is `iTunes` defined and non-nil? I was able to make your code work just fine with iTunes 11.1.5.

Comment: Well, yes. I can for example, get the track name, author, album etc no problem. But can't get the art work nor the volume (i get value of 0) :(.

Comment: @DawidGatti did you ever get any further with this?

Comment: Yes, try this code :) https://gist.github.com/davidgatti/93783042101c310ca806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is as follows.

```
iTunesArtwork *artwork = (iTunesArtwork *)[[[[iTunes currentTrack] artworks] get] lastObject];
albumArtwork = nil;

if(artwork) 
{
    albumArtwork = artwork.data;
}
```